# Facebox - Jquery 1.2.1 close function broken in 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebox, jquery-1.3.2

I am using "facebox" which uses jQuery 1.2.1 on my website here

http://www.pointclickshoot.com/beta2

The rest of my site is using jQuery-1.3.2.js. I need to update the following functions to work with jQuery 1.3.2:

```
/* Bindings */

  $(document).bind('close.facebox', function() {
    $(document).unbind('keydown.facebox')
    $('#facebox').fadeOut(function() {
      $('#facebox .content').removeClass().addClass('content')
      hideOverlay();
 $('#facebox .loading').remove()

/* My added code to REMOVE video_players so vimeo player stops playing!*/

 $('#facebox .video_player').fadeOut(200).remove();
    })
  })

})(jQuery);
```

Right now all that happens is:

1. Video div is removed (via #facebox
   .videoplayer .fadeout) - this is where the movie is, but not the WHOLE facebox POPUP
2. Facebox div still shows!

It appears as if the the **close.facebox** function is broken :/

Here is the full FACEBOX.js file:

```
/*
 * Facebox (for jQuery)
 * version: 1.2 (05/05/2008)
 * @requires jQuery v1.2 or later
 *
 * Examples at http://famspam.com/facebox/
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Copyright 2007, 2008 Chris Wanstrath [ chris@ozmm.org ]
 *
 * Usage:
 *
 *  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 *    jQuery('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()
 *  })
 *
 *  <a href="#terms" rel="facebox">Terms</a>
 *    Loads the #terms div in the box
 *
 *  <a href="terms.html" rel="facebox">Terms</a>
 *    Loads the terms.html page in the box
 *
 *  <a href="terms.png" rel="facebox">Terms</a>
 *    Loads the terms.png image in the box
 *
 *
 *  You can also use it programmatically:
 *
 *    jQuery.facebox('some html')
 *    jQuery.facebox('some html', 'my-groovy-style')
 *
 *  The above will open a facebox with "some html" as the content.
 *
 *    jQuery.facebox(function($) {
 *      $.get('blah.html', function(data) { $.facebox(data) })
 *    })
 *
 *  The above will show a loading screen before the passed function is called,
 *  allowing for a better ajaxy experience.
 *
 *  The facebox function can also display an ajax page, an image, or the contents of a div:
 *
 *    jQuery.facebox({ ajax: 'remote.html' })
 *    jQuery.facebox({ ajax: 'remote.html' }, 'my-groovy-style')
 *    jQuery.facebox({ image: 'stairs.jpg' })
 *    jQuery.facebox({ image: 'stairs.jpg' }, 'my-groovy-style')
 *    jQuery.facebox({ div: '#box' })
 *    jQuery.facebox({ div: '#box' }, 'my-groovy-style')
 *
 *  Want to close the facebox?  Trigger the 'close.facebox' document event:
 *
 *    jQuery(document).trigger('close.facebox')
 *
 *  Facebox also has a bunch of other hooks:
 *
 *    loading.facebox
 *    beforeReveal.facebox
 *    reveal.facebox (aliased as 'afterReveal.facebox')
 *    init.facebox
 *
 *  Simply bind a function to any of these hooks:
 *
 *   $(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() { ...stuff to do after the facebox and contents are revealed... })
 *
 */
(function($) {
  $.facebox = function(data, klass) {
    $.facebox.loading()

    if (data.ajax) fillFaceboxFromAjax(data.ajax, klass)
    else if (data.image) fillFaceboxFromImage(data.image, klass)
    else if (data.div) fillFaceboxFromHref(data.div, klass)
    else if ($.isFunction(data)) data.call($)
    else $.facebox.reveal(data, klass)
  }

  /*
   * Public, $.facebox methods
   */

  $.extend($.facebox, {
    settings: {
      opacity      : 0,
      overlay      : true,
      loadingImage : '/images/facebox/loading.gif',
      closeImage   : '/images/facebox/closelabel.gif',
      imageTypes   : [ 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif' ],
      faceboxHtml  : '\
    <div id="facebox" style="display:none;"> \
      <div class="popup"> \
        <table> \
          <tbody> \
            <tr> \
              <td class="tl"/><td class="b"/><td class="tr"/> \
            </tr> \
            <tr> \
              <td class="b"/> \
              <td class="body"> \
                <div class="content"> \
                </div> \
                <div class="footer"> \
                  <a href="#" class="close"> \
                    <img src="/images/facebox/closelabel.gif" title="close" class="close_image" /> \
                  </a> \
                </div> \
              </td> \
              <td class="b"/> \
            </tr> \
            <tr> \
              <td class="bl"/><td class="b"/><td class="br"/> \
            </tr> \
          </tbody> \
        </table> \
      </div> \
    </div>'
    },

    loading: function() {
      init()
      if ($('#facebox .loading').length == 1) return true
      showOverlay()

      $('#facebox .content').empty()
      $('#facebox .body').children().hide().end().
        append('<div class="loading"><img src="'+$.facebox.settings.loadingImage+'"/></div>')

      $('#facebox').css({
        top:    getPageScroll()[1] + (getPageHeight() / 10),
        left:   $(window).width() / 2 - 205
      }).show()

      $(document).bind('keydown.facebox', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) $.facebox.close()
        return true
      })
      $(document).trigger('loading.facebox')
    },

    reveal: function(data, klass) {
      $(document).trigger('beforeReveal.facebox')
      if (klass) $('#facebox .content').addClass(klass)
      $('#facebox .content').append(data)
      $('#facebox .loading').remove()
      $('#facebox .body').children().fadeIn('normal')
      $('#facebox').css('left', $(window).width() / 2 - ($('#facebox table').width() / 2))
      $(document).trigger('reveal.facebox').trigger('afterReveal.facebox')
    },

    close: function() {
      $(document).trigger('close.facebox')
      return false
    }
  })

  /*
   * Public, $.fn methods
   */

  $.fn.facebox = function(settings) {
    if ($(this).length == 0) return

    init(settings)

    function clickHandler() {
      $.facebox.loading(true)

      // support for rel="facebox.inline_popup" syntax, to add a class
      // also supports deprecated "facebox[.inline_popup]" syntax
      var klass = this.rel.match(/facebox\[?\.(\w+)\]?/)
      if (klass) klass = klass[1]

      fillFaceboxFromHref(this.href, klass)
      return false
    }

    return this.bind('click.facebox', clickHandler)
  }

  /*
   * Private methods
   */

  // called one time to setup facebox on this page
  function init(settings) {
    if ($.facebox.settings.inited) return true
    else $.facebox.settings.inited = true

    $(document).trigger('init.facebox')
    makeCompatible()

    var imageTypes = $.facebox.settings.imageTypes.join('|')
    $.facebox.settings.imageTypesRegexp = new RegExp('\.(' + imageTypes + ')$', 'i')

    if (settings) $.extend($.facebox.settings, settings)
    $('body').append($.facebox.settings.faceboxHtml)

    var preload = [ new Image(), new Image() ]
    preload[0].src = $.facebox.settings.closeImage
    preload[1].src = $.facebox.settings.loadingImage

    $('#facebox').find('.b:first, .bl').each(function() {
      preload.push(new Image())
      preload.slice(-1).src = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/url\((.+)\)/, '$1')
    })

    $('#facebox .close').click($.facebox.close)
    $('#facebox .close_image').attr('src', $.facebox.settings.closeImage)
  }

  // getPageScroll() by quirksmode.com
  function getPageScroll() {
    var xScroll, yScroll;
    if (self.pageYOffset) {
      yScroll = self.pageYOffset;
      xScroll = self.pageXOffset;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {     // Explorer 6 Strict
      yScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      xScroll = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    } else if (document.body) {// all other Explorers
      yScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
      xScroll = document.body.scrollLeft;
    }
    return new Array(xScroll,yScroll)
  }

  // Adapted from getPageSize() by quirksmode.com
  function getPageHeight() {
    var windowHeight
    if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
      windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
      windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
      windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }
    return windowHeight
  }

  // Backwards compatibility
  function makeCompatible() {
    var $s = $.facebox.settings

    $s.loadingImage = $s.loading_image || $s.loadingImage
    $s.closeImage = $s.close_image || $s.closeImage
    $s.imageTypes = $s.image_types || $s.imageTypes
    $s.faceboxHtml = $s.facebox_html || $s.faceboxHtml
  }

  // Figures out what you want to display and displays it
  // formats are:
  //     div: #id
  //   image: blah.extension
  //    ajax: anything else
  function fillFaceboxFromHref(href, klass) {
    // div
    if (href.match(/#/)) {
      var url    = window.location.href.split('#')[0]
      var target = href.replace(url,'')
      if (target == '#') return
      $.facebox.reveal($(target).html(), klass)

    // image
    } else if (href.match($.facebox.settings.imageTypesRegexp)) {
      fillFaceboxFromImage(href, klass)
    // ajax
    } else {
      fillFaceboxFromAjax(href, klass)
    }
  }

  function fillFaceboxFromImage(href, klass) {
    var image = new Image()
    image.onload = function() {
      $.facebox.reveal('<div class="image"><img src="' + image.src + '" /></div>', klass)
    }
    image.src = href
  }

  function fillFaceboxFromAjax(href, klass) {
    $.get(href, function(data) { $.facebox.reveal(data, klass) })
  }

  function skipOverlay() {
    return $.facebox.settings.overlay == false || $.facebox.settings.opacity === null
  }

  function showOverlay() {
    if (skipOverlay()) return

    if ($('#facebox_overlay').length == 0)
      $("body").append('<div id="facebox_overlay" class="facebox_hide"></div>')

    $('#facebox_overlay').hide().addClass("facebox_overlayBG")
      .css('opacity', $.facebox.settings.opacity)
      .click(function() { $(document).trigger('close.facebox') })
      .fadeIn(200)
    return false
  }

  function hideOverlay() {
    if (skipOverlay()) return

    $('#facebox_overlay').fadeOut(200, function(){
      $("#facebox_overlay").removeClass("facebox_overlayBG")
      $("#facebox_overlay").addClass("facebox_hide")
      $("#facebox_overlay").remove()
    })

    return false
  }

  /*
   * Bindings
   */

  $(document).bind('close.facebox', function() {
    $(document).unbind('keydown.facebox')
    $('#facebox').fadeOut(function() {
      $('#facebox .content').removeClass().addClass('content')
      hideOverlay();
    $('#facebox .loading').remove()

/* My added code to REMOVE video_players so vimeo player stops playing!*/

    $('#facebox .video_player').fadeOut(200).remove();
    })
  })

})(jQuery);
```

Also, the following code does NOT WORK:

```
$('#facebox').remove()
```

It physically REMOVES the FACEBOX from the page, thus disabling the ability to REOPEN it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using the `.hide()` function instead of remove.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try delaying the closure of the facebox div for maybe 100ms?

Comment: the #facebox .video_player does not close the facebox POPUP only physically removes the playing video, this is so that when you go to other videos, the previous video isnt streaming in the background

Answer (score 0):

you're gonna have issues using that code in changing the options like ajax and images because that way you're not gonna instantiate facebox when you click on another facebox link.
to close it just use this tag:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='jQuery("#facebox_overlay").click();'>close</a>
```